# IntelliJ adding android sourcepath doesn't work fully

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've attached the Android source code via File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > double-click the Android Platform > source path.

works for the most part, but in many classes in the source, IntelliJ is complaining about unresolved stuff, like variables it doesn't know about it. Many times these vars are inherited from the superclass. Why can't IntelliJ figure this out? It has no problem going to the declaration of the superclass and all other manner of navigation...

Comment: I've been developing for droid using idea mostly for quite awhile now. and I had no problems with it. have you set the android sdk path correctly in the platform settings->SDK?  does it load the Android facet?

Comment: The SDK path shouldn't have anything to do with the Android source code, but anyways, yes I have it set correctly.

Comment: OK perhaps this post http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/07/access-internal-classes-in-android.html and this might give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889689/building-android-source-apps-in-eclipse likewise I don't have classes resolved like import android.os.ServiceManager; and package import com.android.internal.appwidget......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android SDK doesn't contain all the sources, in order to get them all you need to use some tricks like [described in this blog post](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html).

There are scripts that can build a single source jar from the Android Platform build tree like at the link above. If you read through the comments and links in that post you can find [pre-built jars for different platforms](http://download.paul-wintzer.fr/android-sources/) that you can download and attach as Android SDK source in IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse.

Comment: How do you attach a jar as SDK source in IntelliJ?

Comment: Oh, I see.. just set the classpath to the jar

Comment: Where exactly does it complain? When browsing Android source code or in your own sources? Can you provide the specific example of unused variable?

Comment: The "pre-built jars for different platforms" link is dead.

Comment: @KirkWoll, sorry it's not my site and I can't fix it. Also note that recent Android platforms already come with the sources included.

Answer (score 0):

Similar confusion here.  Under Project Structure > Modules > Sources, I had to "Add Content Root", in my case, the directory "/opt/android-sdk-linux/sources/android-19".  Then mark the subdirectory "android" as a blue Source folder.

Yes, like you, my Project Structure showed the proper entry under Platform Settings > SDKs > Android API > Sourcepath, but that clearly wasn't sufficient for intellij to resolve all the Android SDK symbols.