# Where can I find the Android source jars?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jar

It would be awesome if somebody had a link to a list of Android source jars I could download, so I can attach the source code to Android in IntelliJ. I don't have time to be mucking around all day doing this (why reinvent the wheel?), I have apps to build!

I know Eclipse has a plugin that does this, but I don't like Eclipse, I'm using IntelliJ.

PS - I need Honeycomb+

Comment: I don't have a link, but based on experience you're better off installing the Android SDK yourself and using it to grab the jars. If you follow their instructions for installing a platform you'll find the jars here: <android-sdk-install-dir>/platforms/android-XX/android.jar where android-XX is the platform (API level) you chose (e.g. current ICS = 15).

Comment: How about these I just found on Maven Central? http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a%3A%22android%22

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ adding android sourcepath doesn't work fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993844/intellij-adding-android-sourcepath-doesnt-work-fully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there aren't full sources included for most versions of the SDK, you have a few options:

1. Grab the AOSP and build source jars yourself.  [Here is a blog post](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html) that talks about ways of accomplishing this.
2. Look for pre-built JARs that people have hosted.  This is how the Eclipse plugin you mentioned works, and [here is a link](http://download.paul-wintzer.fr/android-sources/) to another site that has the JARs up to 2.3.3; this is where I grabbed the JARs I have attached as sources in IntelliJ.

You may have noticed that you can download the sources JARs for 4.x directly from the SDK Manager now, so really 3.x is the only set missing pre-built JARs.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the source code is by going to http://source.android.com/ and following the instructions on their site which will download an `android.jar` file and a lot of other components of the Android source code. The source code does take up a lot of space and using [grepcode](http://grepcode.com) is a lot simpler.

Comment: Just add a little more info (from the link above): *The source download is approximately 8.5GB in size. You will need over 30GB free to complete a single build, and up to 100GB (or more) for a full set of builds.*

Answer (score 0):

you can find source code online and as a jar file here..
[GrepCode: android - Java Project - Source Code](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/)