# Bad param names when using "Implement methods" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for Android development. But there is one thing annoying me very much. When I use "Implement methods" feature it generates something like this:

```
new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
}
```

Parameter names are inconsistent, I expected to see something like this:

```
new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

How can I make IDEA generate correct parameter names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code is required to get proper parameter names in code completion. Android SDK didn't bundle sources until 4.0 platform version (API version 14), since then sources are available out of the box:

[image: Sources]

If you are using older platform version, [see my answer for the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998234/104891).

Comment: I wonder why Eclipse autocomplete works fine without sources. Anyway thanks for the correct jar links.

Comment: @darja Of course not. I've explained that if there is no sources, then there is no param names for autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't have sources attached, so IDEA just uses .jar to generate the code. The compiled classes don't have information about parameter names.

So, just attach sources.

Comment: IDEA is positioned as the smartest IDE. It is a big disappointment if it requires attaching Android sources just for correct autocomplete. Besides, Android documentation works fine and "Go to definition" on Android classes shows me correct signatures.

Comment: Please go to the definition of `onItemSelected` and attach a screenshot showing the correct signature in the code source.

Comment: Nice to see IDEA developer. OnItemSelectedListener is really inconsistent. But see http://petromi.com/get/40eb0f4bb8.png and http://petromi.com/get/140145ca7a.png. Do you think attaching Android sources is really an only solution?

Comment: What should I see on these screenshots? `getDropDownView` != `getView`.

Comment: I haven't told about getDropDownView or getView. The first is a definition of BaseAdapter class and the second -- how IDEA generate inherited class methods. And parameter names don't match.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with spring `BeanPostProcessor`. Sources are attached through Maven, but intelliJ persists in naming methods parameters `o` and `s` instead of `bean` and `beanName`. When I navigate to the class, I can see the sources and the regular names though.

EDIT - problem was solved by restarting IntelliJ: once sources are attached, you need to restart.